# Format changing when opening excel file in Notepad

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, excel, notepad

I'm exporting data from MySQL to an CSV file in python .while i'm trying to open the file in notepad the format of the text is getting changed.

sample:

In CSV :  `"Hi, Thanks for downloading the application"`

In Notepad : `""" Hi, Thanks for downloading the application """`

if i have Double quotes in the string i'm getting like this :

In CSV:  `"Hi "User", Thanks for downloading the application"`

In Notepad : `""" Hi ""User"", Thanks for downloading the application """`

can anyone help me out with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In every programming language the strings with multiple quotes is kind of a problem.
To treat this as single string you can use different the inside quotes.
ex:  `"Hi 'User', Thanks for downloading the application"` or escape them with backslash .
ex: `"Hi \"User\", Thanks for downloading the application"`

If it's important to repeat often that process ("exporting data from MySQL to an CSV file in python") you need to address your code to fix that.
If you want just to do some operations on notepad, then I suggest you copy and paste the file. In the copy find/replace """ with "" and "" with ". Make sure to match case exactly.

Let me know if it helps.

PS> I believe there are options, to wrap or not the cells in "".